# PHP cURL form field values always empty

Tags: php, php-curl

I tried to access sslforfree.com using PHP cURL but the response form field values are always empty. Here's my codes:

```
$currUserAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
define('USERNAME', 'roberts');
define('PASSWORD', 'mypass101');
define('USER_AGENT', $currUserAgent);
define('CERT', getcwd() . "/cert/cacert.pem");
define('COOKIE_FILE', 'cookie.txt');
$url = "https://www.sslforfree.com/login";
$postValues = array(
    'email' => USERNAME,
    'password' => PASSWORD,
    'a' => 'login'
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postValues);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

 //Check for errors!
 if(curl_errno($ch)){
    throw new Exception("cURL Error: ".curl_error($ch));
 }

 return $response;
```

Comment: Try changing the last line to `return $result;`. You don't have a variable named `$response` as far as I can see.

Comment: use `return $result` instead of `return $response`

Comment: no need to use `http_build_query()`. The option supports array as the 3rd parameter. Missing `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option as well. Please read the official PHP documentation.

Comment: Sorry guys I forgot to change the variable but anyway this codes still not passing the values to the form.

Comment: Raptor - Even if I remove the http_build_query(), still not passing the values of $postValues

Answer (score 0):

use `return $result` instead of `return $response`
b/c when you execute `$result =  curl_exec($sth)` the result of curl execution will be stored in `$result` variable

also, you may need to add
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);`
in case curl is directly outputting the response rather than storing it in the variable.

Comment: Atleast add an explanation as to why he should use `return $result`.

Comment: explanation added

Comment: Thats better, Spoonfeeding people the answer is good but they will never learn. Telling people how to find the answer for themselves is much better.

Comment: yeah. totally agree with you

Comment: Sorry guys I forgot to change the variable but anyway this codes still not passing the values to the form.

Comment: adkstar - I just added curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); but still not working.

Comment: Lewis brown - No need for the explanation of "return $result". When i copied my codes here, I forgot to rename the variable $result to $response since the original variable is $result.